# Mongoose updateMany() not working in nested model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I have a mongoose model called Chatroom which is structured as such:

```
[
  {
    _id: 60cd9816b9326c5cb40ca24c,
    chat_history: [
      {
        read_flag: 0,
        receiver_id: "60cc83b8b0ebb52f43278b1b"
      },
      {
        read_flag: 0,
        receiver_id: "60cc839db0ebb5b9f3278b1a"
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    _id: 60cd9816b9326c5cb40ca24c,
    chat_history: [
      {
        read_flag: 0,
        receiver_id: "60cc83b8cccbb52f43278b1b"
      },
      {
        read_flag: 0,
        receiver_id: "60cc839db0ebamskf3278b1a"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to update read_flag: 1 given a receiver_id across the different objects.
As of now I have:

```
Chatroom.updateMany(
        { "chat_history.receiver_id": req.user._id },
        { $set: { "chat_history.$.read_flag": 1 } },
        { returnNewDocument: true }
        ).then((doc) => { console.log(doc) })
```

and have tried many variations of putting in positional filters $ within the query but nothing seems to be working. Would greatly appreciate any insights as to what I am doing wrong here. The nested update documentation in MongoDB is extremely confusing.

Below is the console.log output I am seeing but the read_flag fields in my collection are still 0.

```
{
  n: 1,
  nModified: 1,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1624101030 },
    t: 31
  },
  electionId: 7fffffff000000000000001f,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1624101030 },       
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1624101030 }        
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, what does "not working" means?

Comment: The read_flag fields aren't updating to 1. Apologies for the ambiguity, let me add that onto the question.

Comment: None of them, or just one?  The positional operator is only supposed to update the first one in each matching document.

Comment: None of them are changing. How would one go about updating all the flags across the documents then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh jeez, I think I've stumbled upon a solution:

```
    Chatroom.updateMany(
        { 
            "chat_history.receiver_id": req.user._id.toString() 
        },
        { 
            "$set": { "chat_history.$[elem].read_flag": 1 } 
        },
        { 
            "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.read_flag": 0}], 
            "multi": true 
        }
        ).then((doc) => { 
            console.log(doc)
            return 
        })
```